# Gradle artifactory plugin * How does one specify the artifact to be sent to Artifactory

Tags: plugins, gradle, artifactory

I am building an android apk: app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk and would like to have it uploaded to Artifactory.

The build.gradle (see below) generates an entry in my local Artifactory when invoked with: gradlew artifactoryPublish, but, the apk file is not uploaded.

Would someone be so kind as to show me what to add to this script so that the file named above is sent over to Artifactory. Thank you.

Here is build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "3.0.1"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'java'

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory'
      publish {
    repository {
      repoKey = 'libs-releases-local'
      username = 'admin'      //The publisher user name
      password = 'password'       //The publisher password
      maven = true
    }
  }
}
 publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                artifact(file('app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk'))

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: From what I see you didn't declare the publication name in the `artifactory` closure, did you?

Comment: yum, how would one do that?

Comment: Thank you for your help!! On the DSL configuration page, I don't see any reference to "publication name". I do see, in the artifactory.defaults closure a list named publications is defined. To me, it is not clear what the list members are. Are they local variables, task names or properties or ... ? And so, is declaring a publication name all that is missing from my feeble attempt above.

Comment: The publication names are, well, the publication names. In your example it would be `maven`.